# Python sort array by another positions array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

Assume I have two arrays, the first one containing int data, the second one containing positions

`a = [11, 22, 44, 55]`

`b = [0, 1, 10, 11]`

i.e. I want `a[i]` to be be moved to position `b[i]` `for all i`. If I haven't specified a position, then insert a `-1`

i.e

```
sorted_a = [11, 22,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 44, 55]
            ^   ^                            ^   ^
            0   1                            10  11
```

Another example:

```
a = [int1, int2, int3]

b = [5, 3, 1]

sorted_a = [-1, int3, -1, int2, -1, int1]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
def sort_array_by_second(a, b):

   sorted = []

   for e1 in a:
      sorted.appendAt(b[e1])

  return sorted
```

Which I've obviously messed up.

Comment: Both `a` and `b` are the same lenght aren't they?

Comment: Yes, they are always the same length. I'm using 0-based indexing, also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
res = [-1]*(max(b)+1)   # create a list of required size with only -1's

for i, v in zip(b, a):
    res[i] = v
```

The idea behind the algorithm:

1. Create the resulting list with a size capable of holding up to the largest index in `b`
2. Populate this list with `-1`
3. Iterate through `b` elements
4. Set elements in `res[b[i]]` with its proper value `a[i]`

This will leave the resulting list with `-1` in every position other than the indexes contained in `b`, which will have their corresponding value of `a`.

Comment: I think you are just mean to derive the ordering from `b`, the values don't matter

Comment: On second thoughts - maybe " I want a[i] to be be moved to position b[i] for all i " means you are right

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand you quite well. The OP isn't very clear about the algorithm, I just tried to illustrate him one way to do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I get a `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: With which dataset are you doing it?

Comment: `a = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]` `b = [0, 1, 10, 11]`

Comment: I'm looking for a new array `sorted = [11, 22,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,44, 55]`

Comment: Ok now I don't understand your question. I thought elements in  `b` where indexes pointing to `a` positions. This dataset have 5 elements in `a` and only 4 in `b`. I don't understand quite well what you want.

Comment: I forgot to mention `b` array may contain indices larger than the length of `a`, so that a new array must be created. If the positions are not specified in `b`, I would like to insert a `-1` in those corresponding positions. Like above

Comment: i.e in `b` I haven't specified `2-9` so I insert a `-1`

Comment: Ok, that requires almost a completely different answer. Can you please update your question with __details__ and I'll be more than happy to update my answer.

Comment: you could use [`for index, value in zip(b, a)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20532743/4279)

Comment: @MarkKennedy: added a brief explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's really more pythonic. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll update the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom `key` function as an argument to sort. This will sort the values according to the corresponding value in the other list:

```
to_be_sorted = ['int1', 'int2', 'int3', 'int4', 'int5']
sort_keys = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

sort_key_dict = dict(zip(to_be_sorted, sort_keys))

to_be_sorted.sort(key = lambda x: sort_key_dict[x])
```

This has the benefit of not counting on the values in `sort_keys` to be valid integer indexes, which is not a very stable thing to bank on.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = ["int1", "int2", "int3", "int4", "int5"]
>>> b = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x, it=iter(sorted(b)): b.index(next(it)))
['int4', 'int5', 'int1', 'int2', 'int3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Paulo Bu answer is the best pythonic way. If you want to stick with a function like yours:

```
def sort_array_by_second(a, b):
   sorted = []
   for n in b:
      sorted.append(a[n-1]) 
  return sorted
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Sorts A by the values of B:

```
A = ['int1', 'int2', 'int3', 'int4', 'int5']
B = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

from operator import itemgetter
C = [a for a, b in sorted(zip(A, B), key = itemgetter(1))]

print C
```

**Output**

```
['int3', 'int4', 'int5', 'int1', 'int2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [11, 22, 44, 55] # values
b = [0, 1, 10, 11]  # indexes to sort by

sorted_a = [-1] * (max(b) + 1)
for index, value in zip(b, a):
    sorted_a[index] = value

print(sorted_a)
# -> [11, 22, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 44, 55]
```